# Which load balancer to use in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-load-balancer

I am new to Azure.

I have two Azure APIs (App services) which send email:

1. One configured to use SendGrid and
2. Second configured to use Amazon SES

I need to configure a load balancer in front of these two app services.

As there are multiple load balancer options in Azure please suggest which one suits the above needs.
Appreciate thank you!

Comment: Did you click "Help me choose"?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, it suggests Application Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this [Load-Balancing decision tree for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview#decision-tree-for-load-balancing-in-azure) which is giving you insights depending on how your app is constructed/running.

As @CodeCaster mentioned in his comment, on the Portal there is also this "[Help me choose?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview#decision-tree-for-load-balancing-in-azure)" section that will guide you through the different load balancers and let you pick the one that fits to your needs.

Basically you have two big criteria : regional vs. global and HTTP(S) vs non-HTTP(s). That is what you need to answer to get going.